# Android Manifest: configChanges:screenSize is not available

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have strange issue. And normally on strange issues I've done something really stupid. But this I have absolutely no clue what could be wrong.
I added

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

to the activity section of my app to prevent the refresh of the listview on screen rotation. This worked pretty well, but after targeting sdK-Version 15, the ListView is refreshing again. I read some more lines and noticed, that I also have to add screenSize attribute for sdK targets 13 and above.
But there is no attribute "screenSize" available in my Eclipse (smallestScreenSize is also missing). I have installed every available sdK incl the Google api's since Version 7.

Please has someone an idea, how to fix that?

Thank u very much in advance!
Best regards
Tobi

Comment: "I have installed every available sdK incl the Google api's since Version 7." - Yes but what is the `targetSdkVersion` set to?

Comment: If you're using eclipse what does the Package Explorer show for the Android version (jar)?

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!!! This was what I forgot. (And like I feared, again, a really stupid mistake. :-/ )

Comment: So you had edited the manifest but didn't change the Project Build Target in eclipse? lol - we all make mistakes. Glad to be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: I don't think it is good idea to build it with higher SDK than the `minSdkVersion`. You can then use some feature from higher SDK, it will build, this feature won't be available on the phone! Ant even shows some warning when you do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click your Android Project, click **Properties**, navigate to **Android**, and then select **Android 4.0.3**. If you haven't already.

If `screenSize` and `smallestScreenSize` still don't show up, then doing a **Project --> Clean** and restarting eclipse. Not sure what the problem would be otherwise...